# Invalid column name error in Group By clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I'm trying to create a Sp for rdlc report. In which I'm using many user defined function for calculation. But when I'm trying to take function alias in group by clause it is givng an error "Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 14
Invalid column name 'CommPaid'" Below is my Query

```
SELECT        Employee.FirstName AS Tech, CommissionStructure.Name AS Commission, '$ ' + CONVERT(varchar(8), SUM(WorkOrderPayment.PaymentTotal)) 
                     AS TotalSales --, ISNULL(SUM(PurchaseOrder.AmountPaidToSupplier), 0) AS POAmount, ISNULL(SUM(WorkOrderPayment.TOC),0) AS TOC,
                    -- SUM(dbo.GetCashInvoiceAmount(WorkOrderPayment.WorkOrderPaymentID)) AS CashInvoice, ISNULL(SUM(dbo.GetSecTechAmount(WorkOrderPayment.WorkOrderID)),0) AS SecTechAmount
                    ,dbo.GetCommission(SUM(WorkOrderPayment.PaymentTotal),SUM(dbo.GetCashInvoiceAmount(WorkOrderPayment.WorkOrderPaymentID)),ISNULL(SUM(PurchaseOrder.AmountPaidToSupplier), 0),ISNULL(SUM(WorkOrderPayment.TOC),0),ISNULL(SUM(dbo.GetSecTechAmount(WorkOrderPayment.WorkOrderID)),0),CommissionStructure.CommissionPercentage) As CommPaid

FROM            WorkOrder INNER JOIN
                     WorkOrderPayment ON WorkOrder.WorkOrderID = WorkOrderPayment.WorkOrderID INNER JOIN
                     Employee ON WorkOrder.empID = Employee.empID INNER JOIN
                     CommissionStructure ON Employee.CommissionStructureID = CommissionStructure.CommissionStructureID INNER JOIN
                     [User] ON Employee.UserID = [User].UserID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                     PurchaseOrder ON WorkOrderPayment.WorkOrderPaymentID = PurchaseOrder.WorkOrderPaymentID

WHERE        (WorkOrder.OrderStatusID = 3) AND (WorkOrder.Deleted = 0) AND ([User].Active = 1) AND (CONVERT(varchar, WorkOrder.ScheduleStartTime, 101) 
                     >= '10/01/2013') AND (CONVERT(varchar, WorkOrder.ScheduleStartTime, 101) <= '10/24/2013')

GROUP BY Employee.FirstName, CommissionStructure.Name,CommPaid
```

When I removed function alias then it give an other error which is obvious.

```
"Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
Column 'CommissionStructure.CommissionPercentage' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."
```

Comment: Look at the logical processing order section of the [MSDN page for `SELECT`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx) and notes that `GROUP BY` is *logically* processed before `SELECT`. That's why you cannot reference aliases you introduce in the `SELECT` clause in your `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Place the complex function you are using in the SELECT also into the GROUP BY:

```
GROUP BY 
... 
,dbo.GetCommission(...
```

The point is, that your alias is not available during the GROUP BY processing. SELECT is usually the latest part of the statement to be executed...

Comment: OK, I just managed to understand the content of your GetCommision function. As I see it at the moment, you should split the execution into two queries. First GROUP BY  *Employee.FirstName, CommissionStructure.Name* returning three values. Then make a GROUP BY on top of the result, having the content of the **CommPaid** available as already processed *column*. The hints we are reciveing are pretty clear. We are trying to pass SUMed values into the function... relying on GROUP BY. This simply, in one run, cannot succeed. We firstly have to group to correctly get SUM

Comment: @Haris - just a side comment - you should avoid referring to answers by position on Stack Overflow. voting (and randomization for identical vote counts, I believe) can and does change the display order of answers - so what is currently the "above answer" may not be by the time someone reads your comment. I'd normally advise either a link (that's what the share option below each answer gives you) or at least refer to the user whose answer you wish to refer to.

Comment: Damien Next time I'll be careful. :)

Comment: @Haris Great to see that. Good luck ;)

Answer (score 1):

Remove `CommPaid` in `GROUP BY`

```
GROUP BY Employee.FirstName, CommissionStructure.Name
```

because by itself it is also an `Aggregate` field

But if you want the two aggregate fields, that is, `TotalSales`, `CommPaid` - you have two options:

**Option 1**: Include the complex function in your `GROUP BY`

```
GROUP BY Employee.FirstName, CommissionStructure.Name, dbo.GetCommission(SUM(WorkOrderPayment.PaymentTotal),SUM(dbo.GetCashInvoiceAmount(WorkOrderPayment.WorkOrderPaymentID)),ISNULL(SUM(PurchaseOrder.AmountPaidToSupplier), 0),ISNULL(SUM(WorkOrderPayment.TOC),0),ISNULL(SUM(dbo.GetSecTechAmount(WorkOrderPayment.WorkOrderID)),0),CommissionStructure.CommissionPercentage)
```

**Option 2**: Make two Query and `JOIN` the two, like:

```
SELECT A.Tech, A.Commission, A.TotalSales, B.CommPaid FROM
(
SELECT   Employee.EmpID,  Employee.FirstName AS Tech, CommissionStructure.Name AS Commission, '$ ' + CONVERT(varchar(8), SUM(WorkOrderPayment.PaymentTotal)) 
                 AS TotalSales 

FROM            WorkOrder INNER JOIN
                 WorkOrderPayment ON WorkOrder.WorkOrderID = WorkOrderPayment.WorkOrderID INNER JOIN
                 Employee ON WorkOrder.empID = Employee.empID INNER JOIN
                 CommissionStructure ON Employee.CommissionStructureID = CommissionStructure.CommissionStructureID INNER JOIN
                 [User] ON Employee.UserID = [User].UserID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                 PurchaseOrder ON WorkOrderPayment.WorkOrderPaymentID = PurchaseOrder.WorkOrderPaymentID

WHERE        (WorkOrder.OrderStatusID = 3) AND (WorkOrder.Deleted = 0) AND ([User].Active = 1) AND (CONVERT(varchar, WorkOrder.ScheduleStartTime, 101) 
                 >= '10/01/2013') AND (CONVERT(varchar, WorkOrder.ScheduleStartTime, 101) <= '10/24/2013')

GROUP BY Employee.FirstName, CommissionStructure.Name
) A

INNER JOIN
SELECT A.Tech, A.Commission, A.TotalSales, B.CommPaid
(
SELECT   Employee.EmpID,  Employee.FirstName AS Tech, dbo.GetCommission(SUM(WorkOrderPayment.PaymentTotal),SUM(dbo.GetCashInvoiceAmount(WorkOrderPayment.WorkOrderPaymentID)),ISNULL(SUM(PurchaseOrder.AmountPaidToSupplier), 0),ISNULL(SUM(WorkOrderPayment.TOC),0),ISNULL(SUM(dbo.GetSecTechAmount(WorkOrderPayment.WorkOrderID)),0),CommissionStructure.CommissionPercentage) As CommPaid


FROM            WorkOrder INNER JOIN
                 WorkOrderPayment ON WorkOrder.WorkOrderID = WorkOrderPayment.WorkOrderID INNER JOIN
                 Employee ON WorkOrder.empID = Employee.empID INNER JOIN
                 CommissionStructure ON Employee.CommissionStructureID = CommissionStructure.CommissionStructureID INNER JOIN
                 [User] ON Employee.UserID = [User].UserID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                 PurchaseOrder ON WorkOrderPayment.WorkOrderPaymentID = PurchaseOrder.WorkOrderPaymentID

WHERE        (WorkOrder.OrderStatusID = 3) AND (WorkOrder.Deleted = 0) AND ([User].Active = 1) AND (CONVERT(varchar, WorkOrder.ScheduleStartTime, 101) 
                 >= '10/01/2013') AND (CONVERT(varchar, WorkOrder.ScheduleStartTime, 101) <= '10/24/2013')

GROUP BY Employee.FirstName, CommissionStructure.Name
) B
ON A.EmpID = B.EmpID
```

Comment: There is an error when used the option 1 "Msg 144, Level 15, State 1, Line 14
Cannot use an aggregate or a subquery in an expression used for the group by list of a GROUP BY clause."

Comment: When used the 2nd option it is also giving some syntax error related to 2nd query. "Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 21
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 23
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 37
Incorrect syntax near ')'.
"